# Array with negative Index on runtime

Tags: arrays, delphi

I'm a bit stuck. I want to have an array like this:

`Array [-3..Index, 1..otherIndex] of Integer;`

But I also need to initialise this array on runtime, based on given parameters.
So `Index` and `otherIndex` are not set on start.

I think I can't initialize negative index in an dynamic array but how would I initialise such a static array on runtime?

Comment: Allocate a dynamic array of the right size and wrap it in code that does the index calculations. Or just use GetMem to keep it even simpler.

Comment: This declaration has abide to constant expression rule (see the docs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrap the array inside a record.

```
type
  TMyArray = record
  private 
    FData: array of integer;
    .....
  public
    class function New(Size1, Size2: cardinal): TMyArray; static;
    function Free;  //only needed if you utilize GetMem.
    property Item[x, y: integer]: integer read GetItem write SetItem; default;
  end;
```

In the `New` function you use SetLength to init the array.
`SetLength(Result.FData, SizeX*SizeY)`.

The in `GetItem`/`SetItem` pair you add 3 to `x` index / subtract 1 from  the `y` index and thus access the real array which starts from 0.

**GetMem**
Another is to use GetMem to allocate a block of memory.
Do note that GetMem **does not** zero its memory, so if you want to zero-initialize your array you'll have to call `ZeroMemory` to clean the buffer.
`GetItem` then looks like:

```
{$pointermath on}

TMyArray = record
private
  FData: PInteger;
  FSizeX, FSizeY: cardinal; //The size of the array.
  .....

//You can use the same code for dynarray and GetMem.
function TMyArray.GetItem(x,y: integer): integer;
begin
  //Inc(x,3); Dec(y,1);
  Result := FData[(x+3)+(y-1)*FSizeX];
end;
```

Because `Item` is the default property, you can just write `i := MyArray[-3,2];`

**Cleanup**
If you use dynamic arrays Delphi will cleanup the memory for you automatically when the record goes out of scope.
If you use `GetMem` you'll have to do your own cleanup.

However, you can add an automatic cleanup/destructor using the interface inside a record trick, see [here](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2015/01/implementing-destructor-for-record.html) and [here](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2015/01/implementing-record-assignment-operator_9.html).

Comment: Im getting a "E2124" when i try to access FData in the New Method. The default directive is not allowerd in a record type, its at least what my compiler says.

Comment: @Vollmilchbb: The New function should be coded as _SetLength(Result.FData, FSizeX*FSizeY)_. As it is a static function, you don't have a "_Self_" and the function result is the new array you need to allocate.

Comment: `function TMyArray.GetItem(x,y: integer): integer;
begin
  Result := FData[(x+3) + (y-1)*FSizeX];
end;` gives compiler more chance to optimise successfully I suspect

Comment: @Vollmilchbb, no the `default` is allowed in records. I just skipped on a `;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lower bound (e.g. -high(smallint) ) you can do the following:

```
type
  TNegIntArr = Array[-High(SmallInt)..High(SmallInt)] of Integer;
  PNegIntArr = ^TNegIntArr;


procedure use(numNeg : integer; arrLen : integer);
var buf : TIntegerDynArray;
    arr : PNegIntArr ; 
begin
     SetLength(buf, arrLen);
     arr := @buf[numNeg];

     dec(PByte(arr), Cardinal(@arr ^[0]) - Cardinal(@arr^[Low(TNegIntArr)]);

     // you can now savely access the array:
     for counter := -numNeg to arrLen - numNeg - 1 do
         arr^[counter] := counter;
end;
```

This is quite optimal from the computational point of view (no procedure calls) but also is a bit dangerous in since there is no range checking enabled.

Comment: There are many cleaner options that don't require function calls